# How can I reset the ADF session timeout with an ajax request?

Tags: ajax, session, jakarta-ee, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have an Oracle ADF application that has a 10 minute session timeout. At the 8 minute mark a popup is displayed that asks the user to click OK to continue. For this scenario, I would like to trigger that same functionality via javascript/ajax. I've used fiddler and examined the http request that gets made. It set's Adf-Rich-Message header to true and add _afTS query string with the current time as in Date.now(). No matter what I seem to do I'm unable to reset the session expire other than clicking OK on the popup. I know very little about ADF but I am pretty javascript/jQuery savvy. I'm also setting contentType to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I read online that a field is rendered to the page with the session expiration time. I've not been able to locate that. My next attempt is to step through the ADF javascript that gets called when the user clicks OK on the warning popup and try to mimic that behavior. Does anyone happen to know how to do this? Perhaps this is the wrong approach? I know the session timeout is set in web.xml, can this be set at runtime as opposed to deploy time? If a cookie is present or something, change the value, otherwise default to 10 mins. I am stuck and open for suggestions at this point.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a bit unorthodox, but I would welcome any idea brought into ADF knowledge base by experienced developers.
Therefore, you can invalidate the HTTP session by firing an Ajax request towards the Authentication Servlet: /adfAuthentication?logout=true

Comment: I ended up putting a hidden commandButton and calling a bean method that does nothing. I click the button via javascript and it seems to work ok. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `af:poll` component to do an idle form polling with some server-side logic behind it to implement custom session timeout logic.

You shouldn't fight the framework, but learn how to use it.